# I can't compile example code, SFML

Tags: c++, linker, sfml

I saw similiar problem, but it didn't solved me my problem.
I can't compile this example code http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.3/start-linux.php . I am following this instructions but I still have error:

In one before last step I wrote : `g++ sfml.o -o sfml-app -L /home/Documents/SFML/SFML-2.1/lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system`

and I got this:

```
sfml.o: In function main':
```

> sfml.cpp:(.text+0x12d): undefined reference to sf::RenderWindow::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode, sf::String const&, unsigned int, sf::ContextSettings const&)' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Can somebody help me with that?

Comment: Could you paste your code please? Also, are you sure that all the libraries are in `/home/Documents/SFML/SFML-2.1/lib`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have't linked the sfml libraries to your program. Further down that page (just after the code snippet), the page further describes:

> You must then link the compiled file to the SFML libraries in order to get the final executable. SFML is made of 5 modules (system, window, graphics, network and audio), and there's one library for each of them.
>   To link an SFML library, you must add "-lsfml-xxx" to your command line, for example "-lsfml-graphics" for the graphics module (the "lib" prefix and the ".so" extension of the library file name must be omitted).
>
> `g++ main.o -o sfml-app -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system`
>
> If you installed SFML to a non-standard path, you'll need to tell the linker where to find the SFML libraries (.so files):
>
> `g++ main.o -o sfml-app -L<sfml-install-path>/lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system`

Although you have included the linking in your command line, my best guess is that the linker cannot find the libraries still, which is why `sf::RenderWindow` is undefined (it's declared, so the compiler knows what it is and thus compiles successfully, but cannot link properly because the linker can't find a reference for it)

Answer (score -1):

I checked the path and folder with libraries and libs are there:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/69UgG.png

But I still can't linkt it correctly.. I have installed SFML in my standard path (usr/lib)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLYG7.png
and after compile it shows the same error.

**Error:**
sfml.o: In function `main':
sfml.cpp:(.text+0x12d): undefined reference to`sf::RenderWindow::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode, sf::String const&, unsigned int, sf::ContextSettings const&)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

My code it's the same as example code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```